# ParsePromise get the result

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, parse-platform

I want to get the promise result of this object [from chrome browser console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JXo2G.jpg) I tried to call it by using the code below and there are no response in console.

```js
var promise = Parse.Cloud.run('retrieveProviderStatus', { providerId: data.id })
            .then(function(result) {
                return result;
            }, function(error) {
                return error.message;
            });
console.log(promise._result[0]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it's a promise your console statement would need to be in the success function. In your example the promise has not resolved itself by the time you are executing `console.log`

```
Parse.Cloud.run('retrieveProviderStatus', { providerId: data.id })
            .then(function(result) {
                console.log(result)
            }, function(error) {
                // do whatever on error
            });
```

Alternatively resolve the promise separately if you need to massage the data that gets returned.

```
var promise = Parse.Cloud.run('retrieveProviderStatus', { providerId: data.id })
            .then(function(result) {
                return result;
            }, function(error) {
                return error.message;
            });

promise.then(function(result) { 
  console.log(result)
})
```